# how to connect to postgresql in play framework 2.0 (Java)

Tags: java, playframework

i am have problem while connecting to postgresql with playframework.

error is Driver not found: [org.postgresql.Driver]

we have added Code in application.conf:

```
db.default.url="postgres://localhost:root@secret/testdb"
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.user=""
db.default.password=""
```

code in Build.scala:

```
"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-902.jdbc4"
```

And we have placed postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar file in libraries folder

Could anyone has suggestions regarding this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that is a valid version of the Postgres library.  Try:

```
"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
```

Then restart Play.

Comment: Hi james, thank you very much.. we are getting another problem regarding the line db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb"   cannot connect to the database [default]

Comment: You should ask another question for that with details of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the [PostgreSQL JDBC driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/) in your classpath ? See the final section of [this document](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaDatabase).

*For example, if you use MySQL5, you need to add a dependency for the connector:*

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
     // Add your project dependencies here,
     ...
     "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
     ...
)
```

Comment: Hi Brian,thank you for replying ...   I have added the app dependencies in the build.scala file as you specified. but still i am getting same error.

Comment: @user1156917, Brian was giving an example. The exact line to be added in dependency is: "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-902.jdbc4"

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing the jdbc driver.

Get the driver from http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html.
Place it in the lib/ directory in application folder.

Comment: Hi Bjarni,  thanks for replying.. We have added the jar file. But i am still getting the same error

Comment: The driver version is correct, as long as you downloaded "postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar".

Are you sure you placed the file in the "application/lib" folder?

Comment: The url changed in play 2
db.default.url="postgres://user:password@servername/dataBaseName"

Comment: we have the code: "postgres://a:a@localhost/testdb".  but still we are getting the same problem